# Importing json in a Python application

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a question regarding a Python app. I am using Python to make a backend. I am using FastAPI and motor among other things.

My question is if I have a JSON file which I will use as a mock up data, how do I import it to the file?
Given the mock up data (JSON file):

```js
[
 {
  "a": "hello", 
  "b1": ["a","b","c"]
 },
 {
  "a": "hello", 
  "b1": ["a","b","c"]
 }
]
```

The only way I have been able to do so is with changing the file extension to `.py`. From `mockup.json` to `mockup.py` and adding a name to the list of documents which will become a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [
 {
  "a": "hello", 
  "b1": ["a","b","c"]
 },
 {
  "a": "hello", 
  "b1": ["a","b","c"]
 }
]
```

And then I can import it like:
`from app.data.mockup import data`

Is there a way to import it aside from this one?

Comment: At first you need to have valid JSON. Your example is not (`'` instead of `"`).

Comment: If you have a file with a valid python data structure like your second snippet then import is the way to go.

Comment: @KlausD. true, my bad I didn't double check yesterday. Nevertheless, in my real casi it is a valid jason. My question is, as in typescript it's common to import json files as mockup data I was wondering if there could be the same in python or should I just declare the variable in a .py and then import it as quamrana said.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you want to `import` this data? You obviously can; put `my_json = json.dumps({"a": {"foo": "bar", "etc": "etc"}})` and then you can `import` that file if you prefer. But why would you need it in a separate file at all?

Answer (score 3):

Python has a `builtin` json package for encoding and decoding json data!

```
import json


f = open("mockup.json")
data = json.loads(f)
print(data)
```

Comment: Remember to close the file after reading it. Or use `with` keyword to open it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not looking to read a .json file inside my python script but rater to importt it as a data structure. However I think it's not possible and you have to use python variables to do so.

Comment: @AlexAbadesGrimes what do you hope to achieve by 'importing' it rather than reading it? Using import like you did in the question will not work in general (consider for example what happens if there is a null in the json-file)

Comment: .. and you can make it properly import-able by loading the .json-file and decoding it in your .py-file, so that you have a single location that reads and builds the required data structure - if you _really_ want to have it available through `import`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `json` to data structure with BaseModel implemented in `pydantic`.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List
import json

class Datum(BaseModel):
   a: str
   b1: List[str]

class Data(BaseModel):
   bundles: List[Datum]

f = open("mockup.json"). # from TheLazyScripter's answer.
data = json.loads(f)
d = Data(**data)
```